# how to get the colour mode of an image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, exif-js

I have been using exif-js library and I can retrieve width, orientation, height, resolution and other metadata. But I cannot find the way to get the color mode of the image.

I need to find out if the image is in CMYK or RGB.

Has anyone done it with exif-js or can you recommend another way of doing it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can read this post about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992117/how-to-get-image-color-mode-cmyk-rgb-in-javascript in the example code you can found colorType 0-6 and color type is associate to http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html documentation.