# Reading ICC profile from image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, exif

Does anybody know how to, and is it even possible to read ICC colour profile data from image jpg/jpeg file via JavaScript in the browser?

Comment: JavaScript in the browser or in an environment like NodeJS? Very related: [How to get image color mode (CMYK, RGB …) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37992117/215552)

Comment: In the browser, I edited the question :-)

Comment: There you go https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js

Comment: that`s exif standard not ICC

Comment: exif-js is buggy and no longer maintained. And it does not support ICC.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [exifr](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr). It's isomorphic so it works in both browser and nodejs and besides EXIF parses also ICC, IPTC, XMP and JFIF.

```js
exifr.parse(input, {tiff: false, icc: true}).then(output => {
  console.log('ICC', output)
})
```

`input` can be anything.

`options.tiff` is enabled by default so we can disable it since we're only looking for ICC.

whereas `options.icc` is not by default so set it to `true`

Also there is a demo [page with playground](http://mutiny.cz/exifr) where you can try it out :)