# How to detect the color mode of the image (Greyscale,CMYK or RGB)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to receive a file from the user and check that its color mode is CMYK only

I don't know if this is possible or not

Comment: with javascript

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992117/how-to-get-image-color-mode-cmyk-rgb-in-javascript) help?